# Bitstamp: What type of order to place to buy BTC when the price drops to a certain value?

Tags: exchanges, bitstamp, exchange-order

I am sure this is a simple question but I am having trouble with figuring out the type of order to place on Bitstamp.

Say the price is currently $1100 but I want to buy only if the price drops to $1000, what type of order would I place? I thought this was a "Stop" order, but the Bitstamp UI asks me to specify the amount to buy in USD if the price **rises** to my given value. I am worried that if I enter $1000 and place this order, my order will instantly kick in because the price is already above $1000.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I figured this out. A "Limit" order is what I wanted to do.

A limit buy order will trigger if the price hits the target or lower. A caveat for anyone unfamiliar like I was: the order won't necessarily be fulfilled at the price your specify, rather it will become a market order which will execute at the next best available price.